# Interact with a running Flash process?

Tags: flash

Is it possible to write a program that interacts with a running instance of Flash?

In recent versions of Java, there is a notion of "attaching" your own process to a running JVM. By writing some somewhat ugly code using Reflection and the like, you can dig around, grab a reference to an object, print the value of a variable, call a method, etc.. Obviously Flash is not Java (duh), but is it possible to achieve something similar?

A couple of things I've already looked at are the various SWF decompilers (related of course, but not the same thing as attaching a process) and ptrace (which seems do-able, but quite low level).

Anyone got other ideas/suggestions on how this can be done? Anything goes as far as language, OS, etc.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could check out the approach taken by [Xray](http://osflash.org/xray), it uses a localConnection to connect to a inspection tool.