# Is there any way to interact with a flash app through code alone?

Tags: flash

I need to run a bot on an app and I'm not sure where to even begin.

I am not trying to cheat anything, I am simply trying to automate tasks using the app. If it helps, kind of like WoWGlider is for WoW (I think, never used it though). So I'm not worried about changing variables within the flash app, but I do need to view their value at least.

EDIT: Pretend some website, flashapp.com, is hosting a swf file, linked to a server which I have no access too. The app has a RNG, and everytime I click it gives me a new number. I need to be able to 'know' the value of that number, and then everything I need to do after that I can just record mouse movements for.

Comment: Look at this question (pretty much a dup): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245374/interact-with-a-running-flash-process

Comment: Could you specify a bit what you're asking by editing your question (for the bot ignorant)? Your have an SWF running from a server and you want to externally view values of vars in the Flash app, from the same machine on which it's running (in a browser)?

Comment: Edited it, I think I might have the point across now, but gah, I just don't know.

Comment: Cool, that may help you get an answer. The answer in short is that the Flash app runs in a VM on YOUR machine so you can, in theory, get in there without too much work. Flash has quite a few protections in place so that you don't, say, run it from your local hard drive. But the easiest way to start getting into it is to make a Flash yourself and try to solve it. Then you can start hacking other people's stuff...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. It depends on your actionscript version, but you can use the Loader class to load in an external swf, which you can then modify the variables of. I would suggest looking into the as docs for your version of flash, and going from there.

A few things to note:

- You cannot load as3 content into an as2 movie
- You need to know what variables to change, if it is an open source app, you can look through it like that. If it is as2 based, you can use flare, or some other decompiler. You may also want to look into flash's debugger.

Comment: It has to be "live" though, I need to use it on a flash app on a webpage (the app transmits data back and forth from their server).

Comment: In fact, I'd rather not even write it in AS3, I'd like to write the bot in Ruby or Python if possible.

Comment: Not sure if that is possible, check out osflash.org. There might be some library. You might be able to write an swf wrapper to communicate to your Ruby or Python. You can use the free Flex SDK for compiling AS3.

Comment: I'm pretty positive he doesn't have control of the SWF, meaning that it's not his...